I accidentally moved the root folder to the backup directory on Ubuntu Server
I accidentally moved the root folder to the backup directory on Ubuntu Server.
ex : mv /* backup/
i cant access all command in ubuntu like mv, ls, cd, mdkr etc..

Can you run backup/bin/ls for example?

no.. i cant do anything

use live session and restore all thes files from buckup to the root

how to use live session ?

This question is similar to: How to use ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso as a live CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Boot from your install medium, in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and open a terminal
Create 2 directories to use as mount points, mount backup and your old "root directory" (aka "slash" or /), NOT simply "root" ("root" refers to the UID 0 user, not the root of the filesystem), and mv things back.
Take advantage of the Live system to carefully backup your user data, user configuration, system configuration, installed software listing, etc., in preparation for a re-install.
If you're subject to "accidents" like this, I'm  hesitant to provide  step-by-step instructions.  Please slow down, be sure to understand the commands you type, and verify that what you thought you typed  and what the computer thought you typed are the same. Minimize use of root (UID 0), and then only through sudo, NEVER through su. Unix/Linux is a powerfull tool, and will let you  make unrecoverable "mistakes". </rant>.
Do something like:
Grab a piece of paper, and a writing implement
(paper does not crash)
# find out filesystem info 
sudo lsblk -f
# I think password is "ubuntu" or "Ubuntu" or just hit Enter, or not required 
# I'm sure /tmp is writable
mkdir -p /tmp/oops/backup
mkdir -p /tmp/oops/oldslash
# Using the device names from lsblk
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /tmp/oops/backup
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /tmp/oops/oldslash
# just in case
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdXX /tmp/oops/backup
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdYY /tmp/oops/oldslash 
cd /tmp/oops/backup
ls -l
# you can "hide" other files and directories (that
# should not be moved back) by 'mv foo .foo'. Remember to 'mv .foo foo' later.
# 
# Finally,
sudo mv -t /tmp/oops/oldslash/  * 
# Here is where you can 'ls -a' and 'mv .foo foo'
#
# mandatory cleanup
cd -
sudo umount /tmp/oops/backup
sudo umount /tmp/oops/oldslash
#
# 


Remove the install medium, reboot.
Then, probably, reinstall, and restore.
Be more careful, hereafter.
